Can i block or modify windows system messages like WM_DEVICECHANGE?
I am trying to use a windows hook to get WM_DEVICECHANGE before the current window(which is created in m code) handles it. But i can't find an available solution to modify the message or block it to broadcast to my created window when the hook catches the message.
I have tried to modify the message WM_DEVICECHANGE into WM_NULL, or post the message to the another window.
But it doesn't work.
I want to prevent the specific windows system messages like WM_DEVICECHANGE from broadcasting to the window i created.

If it's your window, then just subclass it.

@RaymondChen Thanks for you reply. Yes, it's my window. Let it be more specific, it's calling a function of an DLL in a MFC application, and i want to prevent the message(the messages which are generated by the DLL) from sending to the MFC window in the DLL.

So subclass the MFC window and eat the message.
